# How to save/store variables after clicking a button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am super new to JavaFX, with some knowledge of Java tho.
My target is to develop a desktop broad game.
It should ask players for certain options and determine how the game would proceed (like voting, selection rooms, etc)
It works perfectly in Java using Scanner but not in JavaFX;
Whenever I click a button, it only affect the variable in the block.
I do need these chosen options to be used later to support the game logic.
Please help.

Updated - I move the if statement into the action block but it still not set scene to welcome.

```
public class Main extends Application{
Button startGame,howTOPlay, viewRoomButton, viewItemListButton;
List<Scene> playersenes = new ArrayList<>();
Scene welcomeScene, playerRedScene, playerYellowScene, playerBlueScene, playerGreenScene, playerBrownScene, playerBlackScene;
Stage mainWindow;
static int numberOfPlayers;
final static int WIDTH =800;
final static int HEIGHT=600;

;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


    //mainWidow setup
    mainWindow = primaryStage;
    mainWindow.setTitle("Mall of Horror");

    //startgameScene
    List<Integer> numberOfPlayersOptions = new ArrayList<>();
    numberOfPlayersOptions.add(4);
    numberOfPlayersOptions.add(5);
    numberOfPlayersOptions.add(6);

    GameBroad gameBroad=new GameBroad(1);
    PlayersChoice playersChoice = new PlayersChoice();

    startGame = new Button();
    startGame.setText("Start Game");
    startGame.setOnAction(event -> {
        //numberwindow.display is a new stage with a method return a static int
        //gamebroad is class with models, which require the number of players to support its logic.
        gameBroad.setPlayersNumber(NumberWindow.display(numberOfPlayersOptions, "please select how many players"));

        //playerChoise is a class, ok is default fault boolean. set Ok is method to set the ok boolean to true;
        playersChoice.setOk();
        mainWindow.setScene(welcomeScene);


        if (playersChoice.isOk()){//it stop working here
            //welcomeScene;
            Label welcome = new Label();
            welcome.textProperty().setValue("Welcome  players " + gameBroad.getPlayersNumber() );

            Button ok1 = new Button("OK");
            ok1.setOnAction(event1 -> {
                mainWindow.setScene(playerRedScene);
            });
            VBox welcomePlayerslayout = new VBox();
            welcomePlayerslayout.getChildren().addAll(welcome,ok1);
            welcomeScene = new Scene(welcomePlayerslayout, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            //playerRedScene;

            viewRoomButton = new Button();
            viewRoomButton.setText("Rooms");

            viewItemListButton = new Button();
            viewItemListButton.setText("Items");

            VBox playerRedLayout = new VBox();
            playerRedLayout.getChildren().addAll(viewRoomButton,viewItemListButton);
            playerRedScene = new Scene(playerRedLayout, 800,600);

        }
        System.out.println(playersChoice.isOk()); //it shows true here;
    });

    howTOPlay = new Button();
    howTOPlay.setText("How to Play");

    VBox firstlayout = new VBox();
    firstlayout.getChildren().addAll(startGame, howTOPlay);
    Scene firstscene = new Scene(firstlayout, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setScene(firstscene);
    mainWindow.show();


}
```

}

Comment: You need to move the if statement into the start button click action  listener

Comment: Thank you for your response. Moved as recommended, but it still will not go to the welcome scene.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "stop working"? Do you get an exception? Or does the condition in `if` just return false (so the `if` block doesn't get executed)? If you get an exception, post the complete stack trace. If `playersChoice.isOk()` is not giving you the expected result, post the `PlayersChoice` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if (playersChoice.isOk()){//it stop working here`

It did not stop working there. It didn't start to work. It defaults to false until you click `startGame`, and the action does not check again if the choice is okay.

Therefore, you need to setup your welcome actions within the start button action, which only runs after you click the button.

In the current code, that if statement is ran before the button click despite the code having been written below the action. In other words, GUI programming does not explicitly run top to bottom.

---

Your next issue is that you have `mainWindow.setScene(welcomeScene);` before `welcomeScene = new Scene(welcomePlayerslayout, WIDTH, HEIGHT);`

Comment: "This is due to multithreading". Well, not really. All the code that is posted runs on a single thread. The real reason is that methods belonging to the object provided to `setOnAction` are not invoked immediately; they are invoked when the action occurs. The flow of control is something like: call `start()`, then start a loop that checks for actions and invokes action handlers. But all that happens on one thread.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that's why I am stuck.  I will look into how to arrange  threading.

Comment: @Dexter.Z As noted in my comment, this has nothing to do with threading. As it says in the answer, just move the relevant logic to the action handler.

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your response. I move the if statement to the action handler but still would not change to welcome scene :(

Comment: @Dexter.Z Is there even a reason to check the if statement now? You `setOk` so `isOk` is always true... If nothing displays, then something else is wrong, such as calling `mainWindow.setScene(welcomeScene);` before you ever defined `welcomeScene`